# Ninject and Provider Model with Parameterless Constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, ninject-2

I am implementing a custom RoleProvider and would like to use Ninject however I am faced with a parameterless constructor issue. Any thoughts on how to inject for this??

```
public class EFRoleProvider:RoleProvider
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    // I want to INJECT this GOO here!
    public EFRoleProvider()
    {
        IContextFactory contextFactory = new DbContextFactory<myEntities>();
        _repository = new RepositoryBase(contextFactory);

    }
}
```

Comment: This post might interest you: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/ProviderIsNotAPattern.aspx

Comment: Great Post, so basically I should just roll my own Interface and implementation and scrub the provider XML from the web.config as the provider thing is sorta lame. Ok, back to the drawing board LOL

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject something that is hardcoded. Sorry. No DI framework supports this. In your constructor you have hardcoded the instance, so this is no longer inversion of control. In order to perform inversion of control you need to define your layers as loosely coupled as possible:

```
public class EFRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{
    private readonly IContextFactory _contextFactory;
    public EFRoleProvider(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }
}
```

Now go ahead and configure your DI framework.

Comment: When Deriving from RoleProvider you have to have a parameterless ctor. This is where I am running in to the issue. Configuring my DI is not the issue :) The parameterized constructor never gets called.

Comment: @Assistant to the assistant, yes indeed, a RoleProvider is a legacy ASP.NET class which requires a parameterless constructor and AFAIK there are no hooks allowing you to control its creation. As an alternative you could fetch the dependencies from the `StandardKernel` in the default constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking in to how to do that with Ninject at the moment

Comment: @Assistant to the assistant, in the constructor: `_repository = new StandardKernel().Get<IRepository>();`.

Comment: Well that did not work out as expected: Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 It's almost like my Ninject modules, which work nicely everywhere else, are loaded up in a place that this RoleProvider ctor can't see.

Comment: There has to be a place in the global.asax file to control some of this behavior for the provider model. Just need to find it.

Comment: Actually new StandardKernel().Get<IRepository> will create a new kernel would it not.. Then it would not be bound... hmm.. so how to ref the existing StandardKernel?

Comment: To get service from the current kernel, you can use `_repository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository>();`. It doesn't work in RoleProvider constructor though.